# Postgres - insert two value fields with one SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I want to do an `INSERT` of specific values in the defined table. This table has `ManyToOne` relation with `team_member` table. I want to set `id` values for two fields in logs table.

Both fields require the same `id` value from `team_member` table. That is why I repeat same `SELECT` for both values.

Is there a way to not to it like this, separately, and set value for both fields by one `SELECT`?

*Note:* I have one `SELECT` for different table, called `message` table and other two with `team_member` table.

```
            INSERT INTO logs
            (
             content_id,
             title,
             created_by_team_member,
             team_member_id
            )
            VALUES (
                    (SELECT id FROM message WHERE id = :contentId LIMIT 1),
                    'My Space',
                    (SELECT id FROM team_member WHERE member_id = 1 AND team_id = 5 LIMIT 1),
                    (SELECT id FROM team_member WHERE member_id = 1 AND team_id = 5 LIMIT 1)
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select nested with insert should do that.

```
INSERT INTO logs(title,created_by_team_member,team_member_id, content_id)
SELECT 
       'My Space' Title, 
       id created_by_team_member, 
       id team_member_id,
       (SELECT id 
          FROM message 
         WHERE id = :contentId 
         LIMIT 1) content_id
  FROM team_member WHERE member_id = 1 
   AND team_id = 5 
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks you for suggestion. Title has nothing to do with team_member table, just two other fields. Is this sql correct in that case? @FelipeEsteves

Comment: It is. you can just add random text in order to fulfill the need to insert additional information. This SQL is supposed to work.

Comment: you may even call it as a column. E.g.: 'My Space' AS Title.

Comment: I am sorry. Your example works, but I run into another issue. I have one more SELECT for different table. Can you please check the post again, I updated the question and edit your answer. Thank you! @FelipeEsteves

Comment: @FilipStojavonic please, check it out. I included a "scalar" command to do that. since the team_member.id is required twice, it makes sense to let it as the base query and then include the message one as a scalar. depending on the situation tou can do that using variables with a sort of stored procedure but in most cases a insert with a select like that would do the trick. Also included the column's alias to make the mapping easier.

Comment: Wow, got it! Thanks a lot. Will save this for further implementation. @FelipeEsteves